# Excel calculation process / INDIRECT in an array formula

Tags: excel, range, excel-indirect

I got this spreadsheet where on daily basis I will be pasting data ranging from hundreds to thousands of rows. And this spreadsheet is heavy loaded with functions. I would like to cut calculation time as much as possible but not quite sure how excel is designed to process data. Is there a difference between two functions which are ranging like these:

`SUM(A2:A50)` and `SUM(A2:A99999)`

How I look at this: SUM function on first example will stop running once it reaches A50 cell and on second example it will keep running until it reaches A99999. From this I can say first is more efficient to have in your spreadsheet.
Please advice.

I got this formula which returns me an **#N/A** value and I believe this is because INDIRECT is included in array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter).

Whole formula itself:

`=SUM(IF((INDIRECT("'" & $K$6 & "'!" & $K$7)>CODES!$K$2)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$1),{1;1;1})>0)+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:AF5>CODES!$K$3),{1;1;1})>1)+--('Data paste'!AD2:AD5*'Data paste'!AE2:AE5*'Data paste'!AF2:AF5>CODES!$K$4), 1, 0)*--('Data paste'!Q2:Q5=CODES!C2))`

Please find a [spreadsheet uploaded onto the GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_yVmVXbyObQW9zQ2F0UGh0RHc/view?usp=sharing) so it is easier for you to understand what do I mean. Formula is located on **CODES** sheet **E2** cell.

Thank you.

Comment: i honestly think you should use a Userdefined function, written in VBA - this will mean changing your file to an .xlsb file(or .xlsm) instead of the .xlsx which you have. i believe it just has too much data on that sheet . 2000 rows of array formulas is too much.

Comment: would you be able to suggest me where i could get started researching on this as i know that VBA function is a next level of what i do right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, referencing smaller ranges will always be faster or at least equally fast. However, Excel does have some [optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx#xlMinUsedRange):

> Many Excel built-in functions (SUM, SUMIF) calculate whole column references efficiently because they automatically recognize the last used row in the column. However, array calculation functions like SUMPRODUCT either cannot handle whole column references or calculate all the cells in the column.

so that shouldn't be terribly important for `SUM(A2:A99999)`.

As for question number 2: Yes, you may use *INDIRECT()* within an array formula. It just currently returns *NA* because you're trying to add two arrays of different length:

```
{FALSE; TRUE} + {FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE} = {0; 1; #NA; #NA}
```

---

**How to fix your issue:**

change CODES!K7 to

```
 =COUNTA('Data paste'!A:A)
```

and change CODES!E2 to

```
=SUM(IF(('Data paste'!AA2:INDEX('Data paste'!AA:AA,$K$7)>CODES!$K$2)
+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:INDEX('Data paste'!AF:AF,$K$7)>CODES!$K$1),{1;1;1})>0)
+(MMULT(--('Data paste'!AD2:INDEX('Data paste'!AF:AF,$K$7)>CODES!$K$3),{1;1;1})>1)
+--('Data paste'!AD2:INDEX('Data paste'!AD:AD,$K$7)*'Data paste'!AE2:INDEX('Data paste'!AE:AE,$K$7)*'Data paste'!AF2:INDEX('Data paste'!AF:AF,$K$7)>CODES!$K$4), 1, 0)
*--('Data paste'!Q2:INDEX('Data paste'!Q:Q,$K$7)=CODES!C2))
```

I have replaced *Indirect()* calls by *Index()*, which should benefit performance.

Comment: There is a formula inside Codes!K7

`="AA2:AA" & COUNTA('Data paste'!A:A)`

This calculates the range in **Data paste** sheet and determines how many rows I have pasted into this sheet and counters excel going to the very bottom of the sheet instead it goes as far as there are rows with values.

Comment: This puts me in a tricky situation as I cant wrap AA2:AA5 in brackets because of formula. Or can I?

Comment: Oh well, I have seen many threads created where people help each other out to build their formulas but OK.

By the way if I overwrite CODES!K7 into `"AA2:AA5"` whole formula still returns an error.

Comment: Yes. But K7 cell is meant to define a range. I paste data into the Data paste sheet then Code!K7 cell counts how many rows i have pasted in and returns in range format AA2:AA50 then Code!E2 checks if there is any values bigger than Code!K2 cell value. Hope that makes a little more sense. Apologies as English isnt my first language and it is quiet difficult to explain. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Answer updated. Please be more specific in your question next time.

Comment: Sadly your update doesnt work, It returns a #VALUE! error. Copied the cell and deleted line breaks. Where do i look for a problem right now?

Comment: Try it again. Also make sure you have the new formula for K7.

Comment: I have changed K7 formula, i have deleted line breaks, But it still doesnt seem to work.